# How do I make an svg's path follow another elements transform translate path?

Tags: css, reactjs, svg, css-animations

I have a plane svg element which moves up in a curved diagonal and then crashes when it reaches a crash point (a distance after which the plane falls down instead of rising). I want to add a line that follow it through its motion. Like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9KVPn.png

However, I cannot just animate a growing line which also is bent a little because it would not be able to completely follow the plane element. I also cannot just add a path to a different svg because the path of the plane is controlled by a `transform: translate()` property, which is changed in the react file.

There is no way to create a curved line which follow the plane as it moves in the curved diagonal and also when it falls as it doesn't just fall in a straight line.

What should I do?

App.jsx

```
import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import plane from "./assets/plane.svg";

function App() {
    const planeRef = useRef();
    const containerRef = useRef();

    useEffect(() => {
        document.documentElement.style.setProperty(
            "--crash-point",
            `${Math.floor(Math.random() * (350 - 200 + 1)) + 200}px`,
            // Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min,
        );
    }, []);

    return (
        <>
            <div className="animation-container">
                <div
                    ref={containerRef}
                    className="img-container"
                    onAnimationEnd={() =>
                        containerRef.current.classList.add("crash")
                    }
                >
                    <img ref={planeRef} src={plane} alt="" />
          <div className="line"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    );
}

export default App;
```

App.css

```
html {
    --crash-point: 200px;
}

.animation-container {
    position: relative;
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    border: 2px solid red;
    margin: 5rem;
    /* padding-top: 10rem; */
    /* margin-top: 10rem; */
}

.img-container {
    position: relative;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: -450px;
    /* top: 0; */
    animation: moveDiagonal 5s ease-in-out;
    /* border: 1px solid blue; */
}

.crash {
    animation: crash 5s ease-in-out;
}

.line {
  width: 
}

img {
    width: 50px;
    /* width: 100%; */
    object-fit: contain;
    height: 50px;
    /* animation: moveDiagonal 5s ease-in-out  infinite; */
    animation: moveX 10s;
    /* animation: moveX 5s ease-in-out; */
    /* border: 1px solid; */
    text-align: left;
}

@keyframes moveDiagonal {
    100% {
        transform: translate(
            var(--crash-point),
            calc(var(--crash-point) * -1.5)
        );
        /* transform: translate(200px, -300px); */
    }
}

@keyframes crash {
    0% {
        transform: translate(
            var(--crash-point),
            calc(var(--crash-point) * -1.5)
        );
    }
    100% {
        transform: translate(var(--crash-point), calc(var(--crash-point) / 2));
        /* transform:translate(200px, 100px); */
    }
}

@keyframes moveX {
    100% {
        transform: translate(calc(var(--crash-point) / 1.5));
    }
}
```

plane.svg

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" preserveAspectRatio="none" x="0px" y="0px" width="150px" height="74px" viewBox="0 0 150 74">
<defs>
<g id="Symbol_8_0_Layer0_0_FILL">
<path fill="#E50539" stroke="none" d="
M 133.05 28.5
L 132.85 28.65
Q 132.25 28.9 132.35 29.4 133.2 34.15 134.35 38.65 134.5 39.3 135.4 39.2
L 135.65 39.1
Q 139.7 36.8 142.6 32.7 143.55 31.45 142.2 30.8 139.2 29.4 133.55 28.6
L 133.05 28.5
M 133.9 30.7
Q 133.85 30.55 133.85 30.4 133.95 30.15 134.25 30.05
L 134.4 30 136.95 30.45
Q 139.6 31.05 140.45 31.45 141.2 31.8 141.1 32.1
L 134.6 33.75 133.9 30.7
M 139.15 39.05
Q 137.6 40.4 136.15 41.35
L 135.65 41.6 134.9 41.55 135.55 52.8
Q 135.6 54.2 136.25 56.1 136.65 57.1 137.55 59.1 137.95 60.15 141.05 66.95 141.25 67.35 141.7 67.5 142.2 67.6 142.5 67.2 143.75 65.75 143.75 64.4 143.75 61.3 143.65 58.75 143.6 53.75 143.15 51.25
L 139.15 39.05
M 142.45 61.5
Q 142.9 63 142.4 63.9 142.15 64.35 141.7 64.6
L 141.5 64.7 141.45 64.5
Q 138.6 59.05 137.15 54.3 136.85 53.5 137.25 52.95
L 137.8 52.6 137.85 52.5 142.45 61.5
M 135.15 11.7
Q 135.1 11.5 133.9 8.45 131.15 3.15 130.15 0.45 129.95 0.1 129.55 0.05 129.15 -0.1 128.9 0.2 128.3 0.8 127.8 1.8 127.35 2.9 127.35 3.65 127.35 4.5 127.55 9.05 127.8 13.85 128.25 16.4
L 131.95 26.8 132.75 26.5 133.2 26.5
Q 134.8 26.65 136.85 27.25
L 135.9 15.6
Q 135.85 13.75 135.15 11.7
M 129.75 2.05
L 129.8 2.2
Q 132.05 7.05 134 11.95 134.55 13.5 133.35 13.95
L 133.25 14 133.2 13.8
Q 129.7 7.85 128.65 5.4 128.1 4.35 128.8 3.1 129.15 2.55 129.55 2.15
L 129.75 2.05 Z"/>
</g>

<g id="Symbol_8_0_Layer0_1_FILL">
<path fill="#E50539" stroke="none" d="
M 90.75 -2.25
Q 88.5 -2.05 86.45 -1.5
L 85.15 2.9
Q 83.1 1.2 80.95 -0.25
L 76.8 0.6 77.2 1.85
Q 79.25 3.1 83 5.75 82.35 7.7 81.1 10.5
L 83.5 10.1
Q 83.4 11.15 82.85 11.6 82.45 11.85 81.35 12.15
L 79.15 12.6
Q 78.45 12.75 78.2 13.8 78.1 14.45 78.15 14.95
L 86.15 12.9 86.5 7.45
Q 87.75 8.6 90.05 11.65
L 93.65 10.5
Q 93.2 10.1 88.3 5 90.4 -1.3 90.75 -2.25
M 58.6 -10.05
Q 53.4 -7.25 49.5 -5.45 47.9 -4.8 47.1 -3.75 46.75 -3.4 46.05 -2.15 45.8 -1.65 46.25 -1.55
L 60.5 3.55
Q 60.3 3.25 60.35 3.05 60.35 2.9 60.65 2.8 73.15 -1.2 81.45 -2.8 88.45 -4.05 91.85 -4.4 94.25 -4.55 96.75 -4.3
L 99 -3.9
Q 99.9 -3.55 99.95 -2.7 100.45 0.5 101.65 5.15 102.9 10.05 103.9 12.3 103.45 12.95 102.75 12.85 102.3 12.85 100.8 10.85 100.55 10.75 100.25 10.75 76.85 18.7 42.15 24.8 3.2 31.6 -11.55 28.2
L -11.55 28.3 -17.35 30.95
Q -16.5 31.85 -14.25 34.1 -11.2 35.6 -5.3 33.55
L -4.45 35.55
Q -4.15 36.65 -3.35 36.8 -2.65 36.95 0.4 36.5 11.55 35 38.6 30.75 68.05 26.15 76.9 24.35 94.15 20.95 100.95 18.35 106 16.4 107.1 14.5 108.4 12.25 107.15 6.9 105 -2.9 104.7 -4.05 103.85 -6.2 102.1 -7 100.85 -7.6 98.7 -7.65 95 -7.65 91.4 -7.35 85.9 -6.75 80.5 -6.25 75.8 -5.75 71.9 -8 68 -10.3 67.35 -10.65 65.4 -11.6 64.1 -11.7 62.2 -11.9 58.6 -10.05
M 61.1 -2.05
Q 60.85 -3.15 62.5 -3.55 62.8 -3.6 66.1 -4.65 66.7 -4.85 66.7 -5.4 66.8 -5.95 66.35 -6.2
L 61.9 -9.1
Q 64.1 -10.3 66.5 -9.05 69.7 -7.4 72.3 -5.6 72.85 -5.2 72.75 -4.75 72.65 -4.25 72.2 -4.15
L 61.75 -1.15
Q 61.25 -1.6 61.1 -2.05
M 21.3 -6.85
Q 14.9 -8.85 8.95 -4.6
L 8.95 -4.55 13.45 1.95
Q 13.65 2.25 13.9 2.15
L 20.85 0 21.05 0.9
Q 21.1 1.8 20.75 2.5 20.45 3.1 19.75 3.45
L 15.2 4.95 16.65 7.35 21.9 5.6
Q 22.35 7.85 21.4 8.3
L 18.1 9.7 21.45 15.2 19.4 15.8
Q 10 18.7 8.55 18.45 5.7 17.95 -0.05 12.05 -5.8 5.6 -7.3 4.5 -9.65 2.7 -13.45 3.25 -16.5 3.7 -21.9 6 -23.5 6.65 -23.65 9.5
L -17.35 7.7
Q -17.1 9.6 -18.05 9.9 -21.25 11.05 -23.7 11.75 -24.6 12.25 -24.5 14.8
L -21.6 14.15
Q -21.35 14.05 -21.2 14.25
L -11.25 26.7
Q -10.5 26.65 -7.95 26.1
L -15.05 15.35
Q -15.15 15.15 -15.1 14.95 -14.95 14.75 -14.8 14.65 -12.85 14.1 -11.95 14.05 -9.65 13.9 -8 15.5 -6.3 17.15 -3.9 18.6 -0.25 20.7 2.95 21 4.55 21.2 4.45 21.75
L 2.25 22.45
Q 1.45 22.65 1.4 23.8 1.45 24.35 1.6 24.85
L 25.6 19.9
Q 25.8 19.75 26 19.95
L 28.35 22.75
Q 28.75 23.4 29.5 23.3 33.85 22.95 51.95 19.1 70 15.1 71.35 14.3 72 13.85 72.3 12.3 72.4 11.35 71.15 10.9 31.45 -3.85 21.3 -6.85 Z"/>
</g>
</defs>

<g transform="matrix( 1, 0, 0, 1, 0,3.2) ">
<g transform="matrix( 1, 0, 0, 1, 0,0) ">
<use xlink:href="#Symbol_8_0_Layer0_0_FILL"/>
</g>

<g transform="matrix( 1, 0, 0, 1, 24.5,31.5) ">
<use xlink:href="#Symbol_8_0_Layer0_1_FILL"/>
</g>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Sounds like [SMIL animateMotion](https://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/IG/resources/svgprimer.html#follow-paths) is what you want.

Comment: @RobertLongson it only works for basic animations and not what I want. '

Comment: What's a non-basic animation? And why do you think animateMotion can't do it?

Comment: @RobertLongson It would be able to follow the plane svg but not also draw a path at the same time as the paths are drawn using different values and are not animated. The plane's path is not a straight path so you cannot just increase the width of the line overtime to draw it. There needs to be some time of bend but it cannot just be done with `border-radius` so it needs to be drawn as it is animated which I don't think is possible with animateMotion.

Comment: @RobertLongson if you think that the animation could be done. Could you create an example where a line is drawn as it follows another svg (maybe in a jsfiddle or as runnable code in an answer to this question)?

Comment: https://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/IG/resources/svgprimer.html#animation_varieties